# Angular 6 ERROR TypeError: Invalid calling object

Tags: angular

Answer: the error was not related to Angular but a library called pace. Somehow it interuppted the http client.

I have an application that works fine in Chrome, but not in IE and Edge. It happens when I try to call a service:

```
Service:
getTest():Observable<string[]>{
  var url = `https://xx.azurewebsites.net/api/test`;
  return  this.httpClient.get<string[]>(url);    
}
```

Component calling service:

```
callApi(){
   console.log('ddddddddd');
   this.apiService.getTest().subscribe((data) => {
     console.log('ddddddddd');
     this.test  =  data;
     console.log(this.test);
   });
}
```

Auth-interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent,HttpHandler,HttpRequest,HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private adalService: AdalService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        const authHeader = this.adalService.userInfo.token;
        var header = 'Bearer ' + authHeader;
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', header)});
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }

}
```

Any ideas what can cause this?

[image]

Debugger:
[image]

Comment: Can you test it without the template literal string? `` >> ""

Comment: Have you checked if the api is working properly? A simple http request for the given api has an empty response. (I’m on mobile currently so can’t check with postman etc)

Comment: Can you add the stack trace from that error as well please?

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly on Chrome. I make a stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: The trace dosent catch the request. I uploaded image to my main post. Is it some polyfill I need to add?

Comment: It look like as a [general](https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure/issues/109) problem with IE11/Edge.

Comment: Kind of wierd. I just created a new NG project with only a button calling the API. That worked fine. I have to go backwards to see where it start. Hope its not an IE issue then it would mean the Angular cannot run in IE 11?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I figured out it was something else causing the problem. The library I was using used a framework called pace.    <script src="/coreui/vendors/pace-progress/js/pace.min.js"></script> Somehow this interrupts Angular.

Comment: @Thomas Segato, could you please post answer and accept it to show that question was solved?

Comment: Ofcourse. And thanks for your suport all!

Comment: Have to wait for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: the error was not related to Angular but a library called pace. Somehow it interuppted the http client.

Comment: I don't know how you found that but it certainly saved me a ton of time. Thanks!

Comment: I dont even remeber how i figured it out:D Guess a lot of trial and error. But good to hear it helped.